# HTTP error on esp32 while streaming audio to wit.ai

Tags: c++, http, esp32, chunked, wit-ai

I have a problem which I believe is caused by my HTTP request's syntax.

I'm trying to stream audio to the wit.ai API to do a speech recognition and I'm getting the `connection reset by peer` and the `400 Bad request` error.

Here is my code to start the request:

```cpp
void startChunkedRequest(SSLClient client, String server, String endpoint)
{
  client.print(String("POST https://") + server + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  client.print(String("Host: ") + server + "\r\n");
  client.print("Authorization: Bearer "TOKEN"\r\n");
  client.print("Content-Type: audio/raw;encoding=signed-integer;bits=8;rate=50000;endian=little\r\n");
  client.print("Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n");
  client.print("\r\n");
}
```

And here is my code to send the buffer:

```cpp
void chunkedRequest(SSLClient client, uint8_t *buffer, size_t len)
{
   client.print(String(len, HEX).c_str());
   client.print("\r\n");
   client.write(buffer, len);
   client.print("\r\n");
}
```

As soon as the `chunkedRequest` function is called, the error comes.
If you know the solution or what might cause the issue please let me know.

Comment: If you set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` then you must handle a [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) payload correctly. It also helps to try out your code on your PC first (you can write a test program and copy-paste the code into it).

Answer (score 0):

Your `POST` line is specifying the endpoint incorrectly. It shouldn't contain the protocol or server, just the path. Try this instead:

```
  client.print(endpoint + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

And make sure that `endpoint` begins with a `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but saddly I still have a similar error : the server still send me a  400 : Bad request and the connection get closed.
But the error is slightly different so maybe you helped me solve part of the problem.